# C# Web Browser Control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have multiple browser windows within one application from which i need to get parts of the Page Source. Specifically i need to get an ID that gets generated on every page visit.

I've managed to clear Cache using Rundll32 but that window still remains open and no new page visit is generated.

How can I close and launch a new browser window without restarting the entire app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well don't know if the web pages that you are viewing are in your control or not but you can try to trick the browser to reload entire page using some random parameter to URL like:

```
http://example.org/page1.html?r={some random number}
```

I have used this successfully to load images from JavaScript when new image is saved with same name.